# Print with envelope format

Tags: c#, aspose

I'm having an issue while printing Word documents, here are the details:

**Background**: In our system we upload Word Documents, some of these are generated using ASPOSE. These documents are attached to specific type of records called "PRINT". Print Entity has a field called: "Envelope flag"(Yes/No) in which we define if the document attached to this record should be printed as Envelope.

**Expected result:** After we download and open(In Microsoft Word) a Word Document attached to a Print record with Envelope Flag equal to Yes, we would like to see the word document with Envelope Size format(Not as Letter 8.5 x 11 like Word shows as default).

Is there a way we can I achieve this?

Comment: Aspose has a dedicated forum for exactly those questions, you will get far more answers there than here, mostly from their official support team. you paid few thousands for the license, at least use its advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Paper size of Word documents as per Envelop flag. Please check sample code to resize Word documents.

I work with Aspose as developer Evangelist.

```
Document document = new Document("Test.docx");
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(document);
foreach (Section sec in document.Sections)
{
    PageSetup pageSetup = sec.PageSetup;
    pageSetup.PaperSize = Aspose.Words.PaperSize.EnvelopeDL;
    //pageSetup.PageWidth = 400;
    //pageSetup.PageHeight = 679.4;
}
document.Save("Test_envelopeDL.docx");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tilal!